How can I auto-forward sms's from one phone number to another phone on iPhone?
I want to auto forward SMS's from a given number to another phone, but I don't want to auto forward all SMS's.
How can I set this up on iPhone?

Not sure this is possible. Which problem are you trying to solve with this, there may be other ways?

I want to auto forward OTP responses on my unimportant accounts to someone else’s phone so they can also access without asking me. But I don’t want to forward everything.

To set up auto-forwarding of SMS messages from a specific number to another phone on an iPhone, you can use a combination of third-party apps and services, as iOS does not provide a built-in feature to forward SMS based on specific criteria.

Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer to learn more about what we expect of answers. Specifically, instead of just mentioning unnamed tools and services (and forcing people to search further), please provide enough details (and links) to make the answer useful and actionable on its own.
